# Ajax function not returning any results

Tags: ajax

Im trying to create an ajax call when I click a link, the link is the post thumbnail, and the result should show the post content.

When I use admin-ajax.php it works fine, but the problem then is that the URL doesnt become accessable.

This is my ajaxcall

```
    $.ajax({
        //url: admin_url +  '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        url: href + '?action=ajax',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            //action: 'ajax',
            post_id: post_id
        },

        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Succes");
            row.before('<div id="case" class="twelve columns omega alpha"></div>');
            $("#case").slideUp(1);
            $("#case").html(data).slideDown(speed);

            $("#header, #featured, .row").animate({'opacity': halfOpacity}, speed);
            return false;
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error");
            window.location = href;
        }
    });
```

And this is the php in the functions.php

```
  function ajax() {

    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
    $id = $_GET['post_id'];

    $querystr = "
        SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $id
    ";

    $post = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);

    $response = $post[0]->post_content;
    $response = json_encode($response);

    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: By 'the URL doesnt become accessable' - are you after a reliable method of getting an url pointing to the `admin-ajax.php` page?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the jQuery part:

Everything looks OK, except for the fact that we have no way of knowing which URL you are ultimately pointing to. You could see the URL, the headers you're sending and the server's response by using Firebug or WebKit's developer tools in Chrome or Safari, and editing the code accordingly.

Since I use AJAX a lot, I find it easier to just put this right before the  closing tag on my `header.php`:

```
<?php if(!is_admin()) : ?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
    ajaxurl = '<?php echo(admin_url('admin-ajax.php')); ?>';
//]]>
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This way, I have a global `ajaxurl` Javascript variable which will always point to the correct AJAX url.

My bet is that the problem lies on the PHP part, though. You're missing the lines that actually register your PHP function as a WordPress AJAX action. Without them, WordPress can never guess that your ajax() function is actually an AJAX function.

Put this on your `functions.php`:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_custom_callback', 'my_custom_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_custom_callback', 'my_custom_callback');
```

The logic here is that WordPress will check for the `action` parameter when inside `admin-ajax.php`, and trigger the action `wp_ajax_{action}`, which is, in turn, associated with the callback `my_custom_callback`. The first line (the one with the `nopriv` bit), is optional, and you should only use it if you want to provide that AJAX functionality to non-logged-in users.

In your specific case (though I'd **strongly** recommend something more unique and descriptive than `ajax` as a function name), it would look like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax', 'ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax', 'ajax');
```

Let me know how it goes, OK?

Comment: It only defines `ajaxurl` on the *admin side*.

Comment: You're right. I've edited the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Rather than adding ajaxurl to a template file, just use wp_localize_script() (Assuming that you have properly enqueued your JS script via wp_enqueue_script())

Comment: That works as I said, but the problem with the admin-ajax is that when I click the post thumbnail the content of that post should slide up and the url should change to whatever the postname is, and if I go directly to that post the content should already be visible.